# ASP.NET Request Response Cycle: Looking for an event that triggers with every request and has SessionState available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for an event I can handle in the Global.asax of my MVC app such that:

1) The event fires for every request before the request is processed by the application.

and

2) The event fires at a time when the `Session` object (`HttpSessionState`) is available.

**What I am trying to do**

I'm handling the session time-out issue. So, I've got a handler for `Session_Start` that looks like so:

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        string requestCookies = Request.Headers["Cookie"];

        if ((null != requestCookies) && 
          (requestCookies.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
        {
            var requestBase = new HttpRequestWrapper(Request);

            if (requestBase.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                Response.Write("Your session has expired. You need to login again.<br />");
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/?expired");
            }
        }
```

There are some rogue pages that have IFRAME's within them and they load partial views. If the user triggers a request to load such an IFRAME when the session has expired, it will be an Ajax request and therefore, in that case, I write directly on the response buffer for such requests and flush the response buffer.

However, if the user accidentally or knowingly (some rogue user) ignores the session time-out message and tries to re-load the IFRAME, the Session_Start even won't be called this time because a new session will have been created the last time he was sent the session time-out warning, and thus, he will have a valid session. This can be a dangerous situation. I want to avoid it.

Therefore, I want to write a handler for an event that fires at every request, and it fires when the `HttpSessionState` is ready.

The `Begin_Request` won't do because at that time, the `HttpSessionState` object is not accessible, I infer. Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try handling the AcquireRequestState event:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ...
}
```